# Overlay vis.gam (visualization of GAM) on top of a ggmap?

Tags: r, ggmap, mgcv

So I'm trying to overlay a map created by the vis.gam function on top of a ggmap.  However, when I try this:

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggmap)

stellwagen<-ggmap(get_googlemap(center=c(lon=-70.29022976,lat=42.23391413),size=c(400,460), scale=2, zoom=10,maptype = "satellite"))

stellwagen+{myvis.gam(llgam,view=c("long","lat"),n.grid=100,
               plot.type = "contour",color="jet",contour.col="blue",
               too.far = .05)
      points(x=TA2017$long,y=TA2017$lat,pch=1,
             cex=0.5,col="black")
      symbols(TP2017$long,TP2017$lat,circle=log(round(TP2017$sl_pa,1)),
              inches=0.03,add=T,bg='green',fg='green')
    }
```

All I get is an empty map of "stellwagen" and none of the plots.

NOTE: myvis.gam is simply a slightly edited version of vis.gam and it works identically.  The function has also been tested for any errors in coding, and there are none.  I've also tested running the above code with the vis.gam function, and I encounter the same problem.

Anyone have any ideas?  Any help is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example or a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/). Your code requires a Google API key.